# Calculating topic number, where went wrong?

Tags: xslt

I would like to generate numbering for each topic heading.

There is 1 Ditamap with the following structure

```
<map>
  <chapter>
     <topicref href="ditafile1#topic1">
     <topicref href="ditafile1#topic2">
     <topicref href="ditafile1#topic3">
     and so forth
  </chapter>

  <chapter>
     <topicref href="ditafile2#topic2-1>
     <topicref href="ditafile2#topic2-2>
     and so forth
  </chapter>
</map>
```

2 Dita file of same structure

Dita file 1:

```
<topic>
      <topic>
          <title>Introduction</title>
      </topic>
      <topic id="topic1>
          <title>Number 1</title>
      </topic>
      <topic id="topic2>
          <title>Number 2</title>
      </topic>
  </topic>
```

Dita file 2

```
<topic>
      <topic id="topic2-1">
          <title>Number 2-1</title>
      </topic>
      <topic>
          <title></title>
      </topic>
      <topic id="topic2-2">
          <title>Number 2-2</title>
      </topic>
  </topic>
```

Expected Outcome :

### 1.1 Number 1

// 1.1 is generated based on matching id and href

### 1.2 Number 2

// 1.2 is generated based on matching id and href

### 2.1 Number 2-1

### 2.2 Number 2-2

As you can see, The order are not structured. I need to call the ditamap, base on the ditamap structure, compare the dita topic id and ditamap href #, if matches number the title.

Below is my codes

in (topic/topic/title)

```
<xsl:template match="topic/topic/title">
   <xsl:for-each select="map">
       <xsl:number count="chapter" format="1. "/>

       <xsl:for-each select="document(@href)/chapter/topicref">
           <xsl:number count="chapter|topicref" level="multiple" format="1.1. "></xsl:number>

        // if dita map href matches topic id {
           <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
           </h2>             
         }
       </xsl:for-each>           
   </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a fuller example of your input file -- your `<xsl:for-each select="bookmap">` line is a bit confusing, since there isn't any `<bookmap>` element anywhere in the samples you've given, let alone a `<bookmap>` element that is a child of a `topic/topic/title` structure.  It would also be helpful if you could provide an example of your expected output as XML, and of any actual output generated by your code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.

The structure of ditamap stays the same, just that the naming I put wrong.
yes, the <map> is from the ditamap file and not a child of topic/topic/title, is there any way I can call the ditamap? The codes above is incomplete, generally an idea of how to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Are you using the DITA-OT?

Comment: I am writing in xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the precondition, I made the following map and topic files.

[test.ditamap]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
    <chapter>
        <topicref href="ditafile1.xml#topic1"/>
        <topicref href="ditafile1.xml#topic2"/>
        <topicref href="ditafile1.xml#topic3"/>
        <!-- and so forth -->
    </chapter>

    <chapter>
        <topicref href="ditafile2.xml#topic2-1"/>
        <topicref href="ditafile2.xml#topic2-2"/>
        <!-- and so forth -->
    </chapter>
</map>
```

[ditafile1.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="topic0">
    <title/>
    <topic>
        <title>Introduction</title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic1">
        <title>Number 1</title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic2">
        <title>Number 2</title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic3">
        <title>Number 3</title>
    </topic>
</topic>
```

[ditafile2.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
    <title/>
    <topic id="topic2-1">
        <title>Number 2-1</title>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <title></title>
    </topic>
    <topic id="topic2-2">
        <title>Number 2-2</title>
    </topic>
</topic>
```

The stylesheet that inputs test.ditamap and output text.

[convert.xsl]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//topicref"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topicref[@href]">
        <xsl:variable name="href" as="xs:string" select="string(@href)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="topicFile" as="xs:string" select="substring-before($href,'#')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="id" as="xs:string" select="substring-after($href,'#')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="levelStr" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:number level="multiple" count="chapter|topicref" format="1.1"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="title" as="text()*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat(string(resolve-uri('.', static-base-uri())),$topicFile))//topic[string(@id) eq $id]/title"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$levelStr"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: All of the data files and stylesheet exist in the same folder

[The output result]

```
1.1 Number 1
1.2 Number 2
1.3 Number 3
2.1 Number 2-1
2.2 Number 2-2
```

However the DITA map and topics should not processed in such a way. They should be processed by using DITA-OT.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I have made the changes and able to target to the title and the output exactly what I wanted. However, it opens and create a new xml preview with the output. How do I write into the dita files or in the html files generated? Thank you once again

Comment: <xsl:template match="topicref[@href]"> I narrow down to this,no errors, but this causes the program to stop generating the html files, any idea?

Comment: @LydiaPiglet It will be better to submit new post if you are encountering another problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I did create a new thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054839/template-match-breaks-and-stops-working.
The expected output is showing in a new xml editor , just that generated html files , did not fully generate.
The first line template match is causing the issue, I am thinking how does your codes process, as I have a template match for topic/topic/title and replace it with h2, with your template match for topicref[@href], it will overwrite the title?

Comment: Hi, I change to <xsl:template match="/topicref[@href]">, with a / , all html files are generated but the expected output title with numbering are not appearing, do you know why?